# How do I secure all the admin actions in all controllers in cakePHP

Tags: security, cakephp, routes, admin, cakephp-1.3

I am developing an application using cakePHP v 1.3 on windows (XAMPP).

Most of the controllers are baked with the admin routing enabled. I want to secure the admin actions of every controller with a login page. How can I do this without repeating much ?
One solution to the problem is that "I check for login information in the admin_index action of every controller" and then show the login screen accordingly.
Is there any better way of doing this ?

The detault URL to admin (http://localhost/app/admin) is pointing to the index_admin action of users controller (created a new route for this in routes.php file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Authentication component](http://book.cakephp.org/view/172/Authentication). You can set it up just for admin routes with something like this:

```
// AppController::beforeFilter
function beforeFilter() {
    if (isset($this->params['prefix']) && $this->params['prefix'] == 'admin') {
        $this->Auth->deny('*');
        ...
    }
}
```

Checking only in the `index` actions is pointless, that's just obscurity, not security. The AuthComponent will check permissions for every single page load.

Comment: :-) Thanks deceze. You're right checking in the index action is pointless that is why I posted my question here because I was sure that I will get an expert and perfect answer.
Thanks once again.